# Python class error

Tags: python, class, attributes

```
    from Card import Card


    class Hand(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.cards=[]


        def takeCards(self, cards):
            self.cards.append(card)
            pass

        def clear(self):
            self.card=[]
            pass

        def getTotal(self):
            for card in slef.cards:
                if card.value >21 and card ==11:
                    return 1
                elif not card.value:
                    return None
                else:
                    total+=card.value        
            pass

        def isBusted(self):
            if getTotal>21:
                return True


        def __str__(self):
            if self.__cards:
                card = ""
                for i in self.__cards:
                    card += str(i) + "\t"
            else:
                card = "Empty"
            return card + "\t(value " + str(self.getTotal())+")"



from Hand import Hand


class Dealer():

    def __init__(self,name):
        super(Dealer,self).__init__() 
        self.name = name
        pass

    def takeCards(self,cards):
        self.__hand.takeCards(cards)
        pass

    def clearHand(self):
        self.Hand.clear(card)
        pass
```

I am writing a game about black jack but I have some bug cannot be fixed...
I have two class. When I test my code, the program says, Dealer object has no attribute 'Hand'. On clear hand's def. I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Could you post a stacktrace or something?

Comment: File "C:\HumanPlayer.py", line 14, in clearHand
builtins.AttributeError: 'HumanPlayer' object has no attribute 'Hand'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue I see is that you're accessing Hand via self. No where in your Dealer class are you instancing the Hand class. You could try the following with your Dealer class.

```
class Dealer(object):

    def __init__(self,name):
        super(Dealer,self).__init__() 
        self.name = name
        self.__hand = Hand() # Instance Hand so you can use its contents.
        pass

    def takeCards(self,cards):
        self.__hand.takeCards(cards)
        pass

    def clearHand(self):
        # self.Hand.clear(card)
        self.__hand.clear(card) # fixed this to point to our instance
        pass
```